# AUTH_KEY_EMPTY error using telegram-mtproto

Tags: node.js, telegram

I use this code with using  `"telegram-mtproto": "^2.2.2"`

```
const App ={
  appId: //myAppId,
  hash : // my app hash
}
const  MTProto = require( 'telegram-mtproto').MTProto

const api = {
    layer          : 57,
    initConnection : 0x69796de9,
    api_id         : App.appId
}
const server = {
    dev: false 
}
const client = MTProto({ server, api })
async function sendCode(phoneNumber){
    console.log("sendCode called")
    try {
        const {phone_code_hash} = await client('auth.sendCode', {
            phone_number: phoneNumber,
            current_number: false,
            api_id: App.appId,
            api_hash: App.hash
        })
        console.log("phoneCode sent", {phone_code_hash})
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error ", e)
    }
}

sendCode(process.env.PHONE_NUMBER)
```

When calling this script I got :
`[7.244] Error 401 AUTH_KEY_EMPTY 2 1`, 
`[7.730] Error 401 AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED 2 1`
errors, but i cant understand what's wrong with my code, and all I have found is this issue https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto/issues/49, that it doesn't have any appropriate answer

Comment: Did you found any way around ?